# Transfer variables in ssh an get answer back

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ssh, ping

I want to write script in bash to connect to server, ping on it another server, get ip from ping command, and send that info back to pc who ran the script, and at the end connect to server who is pinged before.

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Script to connect to server"
#ip_p used to connect to first server, on that server i want to use ping command'
ip_p=XYz.XYZ.XYZ.XYZ
user='username to the servers' 

#ip_d - in that variable i want to save ip of the pinged server

ssh -t $user@$ip_p ip_d="ip_d=ping -c1 $1.domain | sed -nE 's/^PING[^(]+\(([^)]+)\).*/\1/p' && exit "
echo "start"
echo $ip_d
echo "stop"
ssh -t $user@$ip_d
```

How i wish to work:
domain i want to check test.nyslay.pl

1. connect to server which ip, and username was defined in script
2. ping server(part ".nyslay.pl", is always the same, but "test" i want to read from first argument of script run [image]
3. get ip of domain from previous point
4. transfer ip from point: 2   to local machine, on which script is run
5. connect to the server which ip we get from point: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use command substitution:

```
ip_d=$(ssh -t $user@$ip_p "ping -c1 $1.domain | sed -nE 's/^PING[^(]+\(([^)]+)\).*/\1/p'")
```

The output of `ping` (through `sed`) comes to the local machine via `ssh`, whose output is captured in the local variable `ip_d`.